# Can I drop the hypothesis of being critical point in First Derivative Test?

Tags: real-analysis

In calculus, it is often required that before applying the First Derivative Test, one should check that the point $c$ you wish to know is a critical point. See the reference below. (PS: the definition of critical point here mean either not differentiable at $c$ or $f'(c)=0$.) However, when I think it deeply, I feel that the hypothesis "$c$ being a critical point" is redudant, and can be deleted with no harm. Also, from the proof of it, it appears that we don't make use of this fact. Am I correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it seems redundant. However, I think the idea is that the this test is meant to help you classify a critical point that you have *already located*. So it's not so much for the proof as for the application that they add that condition.

Comment: Yes.  This is mainly used to distinguish false extrema from true ones.  We know that extreme implies critical, so we need only search for critical points to locate extrema.  However, the converse is false, so you need a way to "vet" critical points as true extremes.  This is what the first derivative test is for.  +1 for noticing that it doesn't matter in the context of the theorem, though.  I'll confess that I've never thought about it that deeply.